# How to monitor different events in 3rd party applications

Tags: c#, windows, events, user-interface

I am developing a C# application. I am looking for a way to monitor different events in 3rd party applications.

Example 1: Calculator is running, and I want to know when the user has clicked on "=" button.
Example 2: Skype is running and I want to monitor when the user hits the "Call" button.
Example 3: Word is running and I want to monitor when the user opens the "Font" drop down list.

I am not looking for simple Mouse or Keyboard events.

Comment: Is this a form application? Or a web application or even a console app?

Comment: I am not sure what difference does it make, but at the moment for simplicity it is windows based application with a Form based UI. Actually, the form just have one button "Start Monitoring" and a text area to show different events happening in the other application.

Comment: What do you gain from this info. The only reason I ask as it could be seen as sketchy. If you are polling all 3rd party systems then what do you gain?

Comment: There can be multiple purposes for this information. First of all it can be used to record and then analyze user interactions with an application. Another way it can be used, is to sync two applications one being a 3rd party application. Example would be: A user saves a document in a 3rd party application and we keep a log of it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at EventSpy, Both of those seams to do what you need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11918/EventSpy

http://eventspy.codeplex.com/

Comment: In protected mode also?

Comment: I think both of them are utilities for dev/debug. In my situation the applications are developed by 3rd parties and I do not have the code rather I can only use them. Like calculator, Word, etc.

Comment: EXACTLY!  (What you are proposing to do is write your own "mini spy / debugging tool" fine tuned to your own needs instead of that of general dev/debugging.)  If you can't be bothered to LOOK at the existing tools for a better understanding of what you need then I can virtually GUARANTEE that building it is WAY more work than you're going to want to do.  (You do NOT need the source to 3rd party apps any more than you need source to 3rd party apps to determine what files windows currently has open and which apps/processes are using them...)

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to tap into the "Windows Messaging" loop.  In order to properly filter the GAZILLION messages that come flying through you'll also need to be able to periodically scan through all of the active windows to see which ones (if any) are relevant to you.
Be aware that this whole subsystem of windows is a GIANT security hole.  (I have not worked with it much since NT4 / W95/W98 days so they might have tried attempts to "secure" it since then so it might be even harder to get to than it used to be.
You're going to need a good ide / 3rd party tools to help you get started on your way to have some idea of what you're looking for.

In a "previous" life we used this basic technique to get ~4,000 workstations to install their own software, updates, patches, etc through monitoring for existence of certain windows, controls, etc and "injecting" messages into the Windows Messaging loop to control Application Setup Programs, configuration changes that were not stored in the registry, etc, etc...